# Error loading Swagger doc in the Vercel app (Swagger doc doesnt appear on screen)

Tags: swagger, vercel

I have a project on Github that has a simple doc in swagger, it works normally when I'm only using it on my machine.
However, when I deploy it to Vercel, I get the following error in the browser console:
[image]

And the doc doesn't appear on the screen.

this problem only occurs with Vercel and to check this in prod, you can check the link:

https://board-tasks-back-1k2tyei8d-cassio-ares.vercel.app/doc

to access the route, an input will appear and you must enter the password 'Ares' to access the screen that shows the errors in the console.

the link to the Github repo is : https://github.com/Cassio-Ares/BoardTasks-Back

Could someone help me? I want to access doc swagger with the app on Vercel. Thanks!